# Hypernym for "phrase" and "gesture"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Is there a hypernym for *phrase* and *gesture* — that is, a word for an abstract action of communication performed by a person?

For context, I am looking for a term to use in a computer program, rather than in prose, so a precise but obscure term from linguistics is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: ‘Expression’, perhaps?

Comment: I really wish you haven't added the second paragraph. The first one was perfectly fine, but naming a programming variable, class, or what have you, is expressly off-topic here, precisely because as far as English is concerned, you can call it "PhraseGesture", or "gp6193", or "Susan".

Comment: I concede with @RegDwighт: CommunicationAction will do just as fine as IPhraseGesture.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that was off-topic, and only included it to specify that a precise term is preferable. Please ignore that bit.

Comment: You might want to consider using *Signal.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Symbol* or *signal* might be what you're looking for. *Symbols* being "sounds or gestures that stand for meanings among a group of people". Whereas a *signal* is a "sound or gesture that has a natural or self-evident meaning".

Definitions are from:
Haviland, William A., Shirley A. Fedorak, and Richard B. Lee. Cultural Anthropology. 3rd Canadian ed. Toronto: Nelson Education, 2005. Print.

Answer (score 0):

Is merely  "language" not good enough ? It can be oral, written, ideographic, pictographic, symbolic, and they is a body-language, either unconscious or voluntary. Even the road-signs are a convention expression of concepts.
The word covers any way of communication.

Comment: Well, *language* certainly covers written or spoken language (which *contain* phrases), as well as body language (which *contains* gestures), but what I am looking for is a word that covers *phrase* and *gesture*.